# Searching for marked (selected) text in Emacs

Tags: search, emacs, text, text-editor

I use emacs for viewing and editing code and other text files. I wanted to know if there is a way to search forward or backward for text which is marked in the current buffer. Similar to what I can do in notepad or wordpad. As in can I mark some text in the buffer and do a C-s or C-r and be able to search with the marked text without actually typing in the whole search text?

Thank you,

Rohit

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes.  `M-W` (to get a copy of the selected text) `C-s <RET> C-y <RET>`.  Then repeat `C-s` as needed.  Similarly for `C-r`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Incidentally, the relevant section of the manual is "20.1 Basics of Incremental Search". C-h i d m emacs<RET> g Basic Isearch <RET> http://www.manpagez.com/info/emacs/emacs_95.php

Comment: That is how I already did it ... I am somewhat surprised there isn't a single built-in command for this.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to search for marked text. This explains how to search for copied text.

Answer (score 115):

@Alex nails it.

Another option I use quite often is `C-s C-w` to search for the word after the current mark. Hitting `C-w` repeatedly increases the search with additional words (e.g., `C-s C-w C-w C-w` searches for the 3 words after the current mark).

Similarly, `C-s M-s C-e` searches for the rest of the line after the current mark and `C-s C-M-y` searches for the character after the mark. These are both repeatable in the same way (the former by somewhat-awkwardly repeating `M-s C-e` after `C-s`).

Comment: Likewise, `C-r C-w` searches backward ("r" = reverse) for the word after the mark.  And `C-r C-w C-w` searches backward for the two words after the mark.

Comment: The function `C-s C-y` used to be bound to is now bound to `C-s M-s C-e` (since Emacs 24.1) [[source](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IncrementalSearch)].

Answer (score 17):

I am using the following which does not have the problem of having to type more then one successive C-s to find later occurences:

```
    (defun search-selection (beg end)
      "search for selected text"
      (interactive "r")
      (kill-ring-save beg end)
      (isearch-mode t nil nil nil)
      (isearch-yank-pop)
    )
    (define-key global-map (kbd "<C-f3>") 'search-selection)
```

The disadvantage of the previous code is that the selected text is copied to the stretch. The following code does not have this problem:

```
    (defun search-selection (beg end)
      "search for selected text"
      (interactive "r")
      (let (
            (selection (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end))
           )
        (deactivate-mark)
        (isearch-mode t nil nil nil)
        (isearch-yank-string selection)
      )
    )
    (define-key global-map (kbd "<C-f3>") 'search-selection)
```

Answer (score 8):

Other answers describe how to search for copied text, or how to search for the word at point. But none of them actually describe how to "search with the marked text."

Adding the following hook will make it so that the currently-selected text is the text used for an isearch:

```
(defun jrh-isearch-with-region ()
  "Use region as the isearch text."
  (when mark-active
    (let ((region (funcall region-extract-function nil)))
      (deactivate-mark)
      (isearch-push-state)
      (isearch-yank-string region))))

(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook #'jrh-isearch-with-region)
```

Tip: This pairs nicely with [expand-region](http://emacsrocks.com/e09.html).

Comment: I think it works better if you make two modifications: add `(goto-char (region-beginning))` before `(deactivate-mark)` to prevent moving straight to the next match when the function is called, and replace `(isearch-push-state)` with `(isearch-update)`; with `(isearch-push-state)`, if it's called repeatedly on the same piece of text it stops highlighting the other occurrences.

Answer (score 5):

The shortest key sequence to do this is <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>.

Comment: It's worth noting this searches for the lower case of the word even if you're highlighting all uppercase text.

Comment: This is a keystroke, not a command, which means it's meaningless in any environment that happens to override that. It sends us on a wild goose chase to figure out what command you're trying to refer to.

Answer (score 4):

There is a great function for this: `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point`. It highlights all occurrences of the word where your point is located - no need to place the point at the beginning of the word. Then you can move to next or previous with C-s or C-r.

Note that it is an exact match: if you use it on `hi` it won't match `chill` for instance.

I mapped if to `command-f` (mac OSX):  `(global-set-key (kbd "s-f") 'isearch-forward-symbol-at-point)` in the init file.

Comment: This does (nearly) precisely what the question asks for.  The only difference is that `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` automatically selects the text at point. This can be problematic if what you consider a word differs from what Emacs considers a word.  Still useful, though.  The default binding on GNU Emacs 24.5.1 is `M-s .`.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above (including the accepted one) are too cumbersome IMHO. I found the following info and like it well better:

> “Ctrl+s Ctrl+w”. This will search the current word, but you must move
>   your cursor to the beginning of the word first.

http://xah-forum.blogspot.com/2009/08/search-word-under-cursor-in-emacs.html

Comment: Well, that is exactly what @chris-conway pointed on https://stackoverflow.com/a/203026/316232.

Answer (score 0):

You can find C-s help by doing C-h k C-s, and it says:

> Type DEL to cancel last input item from end of search string. Type RET
>   to exit, leaving point at location found. Type LFD (C-j) to match end
>   of line. Type C-s to search again forward, C-r to search again
>   backward. ***Type C-w to yank next word or character in buffer***   onto the
>   end of the search string, and search for it. Type C-M-w to delete
>   character from end of search string. Type C-M-y to yank char from
>   buffer onto end of search string and search for it. Type M-s C-e to
>   yank rest of line onto end of search string and search for it. Type
>   C-y to yank the last string of killed text. Type M-y to replace string
>   just yanked into search prompt  with string killed before it. Type C-q
>   to quote control character to search for it. Type C-x 8 RET to add a
>   character to search by Unicode name, with completion. C-g while
>   searching or when search has failed cancels input back to what has 
>   been found successfully. C-g when search is successful aborts and
>   moves point to starting point.
>
> If you try to exit with the search string still empty, it invokes 
>   nonincremental search.
>
> Type M-c to toggle search case-sensitivity. Type M-s i to toggle
>   search in invisible text. Type M-r to toggle regular-expression mode.
>   Type M-s w to toggle word mode. Type M-s _ to toggle symbol mode. Type
>   M-s ' to toggle character folding.
>
> Type M-s SPC to toggle whitespace matching. In incremental searches, a
>   space or spaces normally matches any whitespace defined by the
>   variable ‘search-whitespace-regexp’; see also the variables
>   ‘isearch-lax-whitespace’ and ‘isearch-regexp-lax-whitespace’.
>
> Type M-s e to edit the search string in the minibuffer.
>
> Also supported is a search ring of the previous 16 search strings.
>   Type M-n to search for the next item in the search ring. Type M-p to
>   search for the previous item in the search ring. Type C-M-i to
>   complete the search string using the search ring.
>
> Type M-% to run ‘query-replace’ with string to replace from last
>   search string. Type C-M-% to run ‘query-replace-regexp’ with the last
>   search string. Type M-s o to run ‘occur’ that shows the last search
>   string. Type M-s h r to run ‘highlight-regexp’ that highlights the
>   last search string.
>
> Type C-h b to display all Isearch key bindings. Type C-h k to display
>   documentation of Isearch key. Type C-h m to display documentation of
>   Isearch mode.

Answer (score 0):

Adopted [Jackson's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32002122/15324798) for [Swiper](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper):

```lisp
 (defun swiper-isearch-selected ()
    "Use region as the isearch text."
    (interactive)
    (if mark-active
      (swiper-isearch (funcall region-extract-function nil))
      (swiper-isearch)))
```

Additionally, if there is no selected region, it just falls back to the regular `swiper-isearch`.